# In SQL Auditing parameter real values are not shown

Tags: sql, auditing, sql-server-2022

I am using SQL server 2022 Developer Edition (with CU10 Patch).
On this server, I enabled the SQL server Auditing Service and created a Database level Actions/Triggers (CRUD).
I am using the Stored procedure to perform the CRUD operation on database tables.

When any changes happen in a database table, an Audit event is generated.

**Statement** column value in the audit event is shown like this

```
UPDATE [servers] SET [last_status_report]=@P1
```

Instead of

```
UPDATE [servers] SET [last_status_report]='2024-01-16 04:10:55'
```

What do I need to change to view the real value in auditing events instead of @p1?

Note: When I Add **BATCH_COMPLETED_GROUP** Action group on the database level then it shows stored procedure details and real value data in the statement column but I want UPDATE query with real value data.